# The role-to-implement of interface in Typescript

Tags: interface, typescript

All:

I am pretty new to typescript, when come to the concept of interface, first example I met is for implement by class like:

```
interface ITax {
    taxpayerId: string;
    calculateTax(): number;
}

class IncomeTax implements ITax {
    taxpayerId: string;
    calculateTax(): number {
       return 10000;
    }
}
```

I wonder if every class needs to redeclare the member taxpayerId, **why do we need to define it in interface**( this really confuses me comparing with JAVA, also I find some posts dont redeclare member in interface, but in my case: Sublime+typescript, I got error says taxpayerId is missing in type in IncomeTax  if I dont declare that member in class)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a distinction in TypeScript (and other languages) between *implementing* an interface, and *inheriting* from (or *extending*) a class. Like C#, an interface in TypeScript is purely abstract, with no implementation associated with it. Consequently, classes that implement that interface need to provide their own implementation, whether of fields or of methods, makes no difference. However, if they're *extending* a base class, they don't: they can override the base implementation, of course (no need for a `virtual` keyword, as effectively everything is virtual), but they don't *need* to.

Now that Typescript supports abstract classes, you could also implement it like this:

```
abstract class Tax {
    taxpayerId: string;
    abstract calculateTax(): number;
}

class IncomeTax extends Tax {
    calculateTax(): number {
        return 10000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, like I said, I got error if I did not put member declare in class, do you get same error?

Comment: Yes, you'll get that error if you're trying to implement an interface and don't provide all the relevant properties and methods. But see the `abstract` key I demonstrate above - that's closer to what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.